# Remover Dialogo de impressora - PrintJob Java

Tags: java, impressão

Em uma aplicação Java faço a impressão por meio de PrintJob, porém da forma que faço a impressão ao chamar o método Imprimir ele abre uma caixa de dialogo da impressora para que eu escolha em qual devo imprimir, eu tentei e não consegui fazer com que imprima sem ter que chamar o dialogo.

Segue abaixo a meu metodo de impressão.

Imprimir.java

```
public void imprimir() {


    Frame f = new Frame("Frame temporário");
    f.setSize((int) 283.46, 500);
    f.pack();


    Toolkit tk = f.getToolkit();

    PrintJob pj = tk.getPrintJob(f, "MP4200", null);



    if (pj != null) {
        Graphics g = pj.getGraphics();

    ...Aqui vai os dados impressos...


        g.dispose();

        pj.end();
    }


    f.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode estar tentando adaptar este exemplo que fiz amigo para a sua necessidade. Nele eu imprimo um objeto da classe Desenho que deve implementar **Printable** para que seja um objeto imprimível, ai eu chamo na classe principal o método **print()** do objeto **PrinterJob**, assim ele vai mandar imprimir direto na impessora, sem exibir o dialogo, quando você tenta imprimir de um **PrinterJob** de um **Toolkit** sempre vai exibir a caixa de dialogo das impressoras, não há solução nesse sentido.

Classe do objeto a ser impresso.

```
public class Desenho implements Printable {
    // Deve implementar Printable para que seja um objeto imprimivel

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex)
            throws PrinterException {
        if (pageIndex > 0) {
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        } else {
            // Renderiza um quadrado
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
            int x = 90;
            int y = 90;
            g2d.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, 500, 500));

            // Mostra que imprimiu o objeto
            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
    }
}
```

E a classe de teste

`public class Impressora {`

```
// Classe main para testar o exemplo
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Impressora imp = new Impressora();
    imp.imprimir();
}

public void imprimir() {
    PrinterJob impressor = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    // Informo ao impressor o objeto que quero imprimir
    impressor.setPrintable(new Desenho()); 
    try {
        // Manda imprimir diretamente na impressora padrão
        impressor.print();
        // Abre a caixa de dialogo de impressão
        // impressor.printDialog();
    } catch (PrinterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}